# Execute stored procedure with format option

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure in python with multiple parameters.

I've been successful with executing similar stored procedure for a single parameter. This is the syntax I used for single parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server="<server>",database="<database>",uid="<username>",pwd="<password>")

sql_query = """SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC database..stored_procedure '{0}';""".format(int(customer))
            
dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query , connecting)
```

I need assistance with extrapolating this to multiple parameters. This is what I tried but not getting expected results, I'm only getting the column headers.

```
sql_query = """SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC database..stored_procedure '{0}, {0}';""".format(int(customer), int(price))
            
dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query , connecting)
```

Note that the stored procedure is executing correctly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Edit 1:
This code works:

```
sql = """SET NOCOUNT ON;  EXEC database..stopred_procedure @customer=?, @price=?  """  
params = (int(customer),int(price))  
cursor.execute(sql, params)   
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

The problem is that it does not give results as a data frame which is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work by doing the following:

```
query = "SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC database..stored_procedure @customer=?, @price=?"
cust_id = 147
prices = 200
data_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connecting, params=(cust_id, prices ))
```

This way, I was able to get results in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in passing 2 values You should have 2 indices `{0},{1}` for the same.See the examples below.

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'

>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'c, b, a'
```

More info on the [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples)

Updated Code:

```
sql_query = """SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC database..stored_procedure {0}, {1}""".format(int(customer), int(price))
```

Comment: now I get another error ```DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'EXEC database..stored_procedure 'henry,200';': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'database..stored_procedure' expects parameter '@price', which was not supplied. (201) (SQLExecDirectW)") ```

Comment: This code works: ```sql = """SET NOCOUNT ON;  EXEC database..stopred_procedure @customer=?, @price=?  """
 params = (str(customer),int(price))
 cursor.execute(sql, params)
  data = cursor.fetchone() ``` The problem is that it does not give results as a data frame which is what I want.